# Natural action of $S_n$ on $\{ 1,2,\dots,n \}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

From reading online the "natural" action of $S_n$ on $\{ 1,2,\dots,n \}$ is $(g,x) \mapsto gx$. How is this action transitive? As far as I can see if we take $g$ to fix some element we will not get a transitive action as there will be $2$ or more orbits.

Comment: That the action is transitive means that for all $x,y$ there is a $g\in S_n$ with $gx = y$. You can explicitly write down such a $g$.

Comment: I have the definition as "there is only one orbit". How is that equivalent?

Comment: @sandstone it is equivalent because the existence of $g$ with $gx=y$ is equivalent to $x,y$ being in the same orbit.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for that I see this now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Transitive" means that every point in $\{1$,...,n$\}$ is mapped to every other point by the action. Equivalently, the action is transitive if the orbit of any point $x$ under the action is the whole set.
In this case the orbit of any $x \in \{1,2,...n\}$ is $S_{n}(x) = \{1,...,n\}$ (consider acting by permutations $(x1),(x2),...,(xn)$), so the action is indeed transitive. 
You have claimed that the *stabiliser*  of any particular point is not necessarily trivial, which is correct but a separate issue.